# "package or namespace load failed" error in loading R package from GitHub

Tags: r, github

I am trying to load a package in RStudio from GitHub but I get an error.
I have also updated all the packages in order to see if this was the problem but I still get the same error. I have a MAC pc (I don't know if this may cause some problems).

The link of the package that I would like to load is:
https://github.com/andrewraim/COMMultReg

and there is written that in order to load it I need to run

```
library(devtools)
install_github("andrewraim/COMMultReg")
```

But when I run the second line I get as error:

```
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘COMMultReg’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: d_cmb, d_cmb_sample, d_cmm, d_cmm_sample, gunterize, loglik_score_fim_cmm, normconst_cmb, normconst_cmm, r_cmb
Errore: loading failed
Esecuzione interrotta
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/COMMultReg’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/n0/4lmr1lrj7qqfylmh6s8qx0nr0000gn/T//RtmpldrmHr/file72e1e4469d/COMMultReg_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can somebody help me telling me what to do?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package has no function named `d_cmb`, but it tries to export that function.  That's what the error message says, and it's true.

I think the reason for this error is that the author used Roxygen2 to generate his `NAMESPACE` file where the exports are declared, but that file is out of sync with the contents of the package.

It's possible this happened because the author forgot to commit a new file containing the new code.  In that case, the best solution is to contact the author, and point out the issue.

Alternatively, it may have happened because at one time there was a `d_cmb` function, but the author removed it, without updating the `NAMESPACE` file.  This one you might be able to fix yourself.

To fix this, you'll need to run Roxygen2 yourself, which is a little more complicated than just installing what's on Github.  Here are the steps:

- Fork the package to your own Github account if you have one.  (This step is optional, but it makes some later steps easier.)
- Download the source for the package.  In RStudio, the quickest way to do this is to create a new project using Version Control, Git, and give the URL
  of your forked copy, or the original URL if you skipped that.
- Run Roxygen2 on the package.  In RStudio, you do this by choosing "Document" in the "More" menu of the Build tab.
- Try to build it.  If you're lucky, it will now build properly.  If not, fix the next problem.
- This is very important:  send your changes back to the original author.  If you forked the package, this is easy; if not, figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Hi!, thanks for the reply. I don't find "Document" in the "More " menu of the build tab... how can I do?

Comment: You probably need to "configure build tools", choosing "Generate documentation with Roxygen", and make sure NAMESPACE is checked in the "Roxygen options" you get if you click the "Configure..." button for Roxygen.

Comment: It all worked and now I have a R project where I can use this package. But how do I send my changes back to the original author? (I have forked the package)

Comment: The Github main page for the branch you were working on should have a "Compare" or "pull request" link on it just above the list of files.  Click on that, follow the instructions, and you'll prepare a "pull request" to go back to the original author.

Answer (score 1):

this is the maintainer of the COMMultReg package. I didn't know about this thread until now, but it sounds like you were able to get started from the answer by `user2554330`.

The functions `d_cmb`, `d_cmb_sample`, etc are supposed to be exported. I think the problem may have been that, at the time of the question, I did not have `src/RcppExports.cpp` and `R/RcppExports.R` checked into Github. This seems to be necessary to use `install_github` on a package with exported Rcpp functions. Those were checked in around 8 months ago. (Coincidentally not long after this question was posted?)

Please let me know if you still having trouble with the install. Otherwise, enjoy the package!